# tinymce making picture stuck (?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

If u look at this picture: 
[image]

You see that i have a picture in my editor..

That picture loads when the content loads in the editor like this:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    theme: "modern",
    height: 650,
    language : 'sv_SE',
    menubar: false,
    statusbar: false,
    object_resizing: false,
    setup: function(editor) { 
        editor.on('BeforeSetContent', function(e) { 
            e.content = '<img src="../img/users/1.jpg" width="150" height="150" style="float:left;margin-right:10px;">' + e.content;
        });
    }
});
```

My question now is, is there a way to go to make this picture undeletable?

Right now u can just press backspace and the picture disappears or click on the image and press delete.. Is it a way to make it "stuck" ? I'm all out of ideas now and i hope u can help me!

Now after some struggeling i got the classname but i still can remove the picture, any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    theme: "modern",
    height: 650,
    language : 'sv_SE',
    menubar: false,
    statusbar: false,
    plugins: "noneditable",
    object_resizing: false,
    setup : function(editor) {
        editor.on("BeforeSetContent", function(e) { 
            e.content = '<img src="../img/users/1.jpg" width="150" height="150" class="mceNonEditable" style="float:left;margin-right:10px;">' + e.content;
        });
        editor.on("click", function(e) { 
            if ($(e.target).attr('class') == "mceNonEditable") { 
                this.preventDefault();
            }

        });
    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: Probably we can't do that but there is a way. Tinymce will store the whole text into html elements internally for that image just inspect that and disable some events. Like if we press backspace or click on the image write a event to do nothing.

Comment: @VenkatLokeswar good idea.
But i propse to try with noneditable plugin.
https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/noneditable/